# Prevent editing of specific subform fields in MS Access

Tags: forms, validation, ms-access, locking, edit

I have a subform in a data entry form, which has field labels that are textboxes with content that comes from a separate table to the checkboxes they sit next to. The field labels are changed by a dropdown list, which changes the category that the checkboxes belong to and consequently changes their meaning. I need to prevent the field labels (textboxes) being edited, but I can't use the 'Allow Edits [No]' property of the subform (because that locks the dropdown and prevent the field labels being changed) and I can't lock the specific field label textboxes, because they need to change when a new value is chosen in the drop down list.

Any suggestions? I rarely use Access or VBA, so am a bit stumped. Is a validation rule a possibility?

Comment: Are you using an `After Update` [Event Procedure] for the combo box to update the "field labels"?

Comment: No, this is done via an SQL query.

Comment: Hmm, okay...  the user selects a new item from the drop-down list (combobox) and the field labels (textboxes) get updated. What triggers that update? Even if the `Control Source` for the textboxes is a query of some kind I would expect that there needs to be a `Requery` (or equivalent) to make the changes actually happen.

Comment: I can see your reasoning, but there is nothing in the Event tabs of the combo box properties or the 'field labels' properties. The SQL query is in the record source of the form, and the update of 'field labels' happens automatically when a new value is chosen in the combobox. It's Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

when you say "label", do you mean "textboxes"? If you add a label control to a form the user cannot change them, this is only possible in design mode or with VBA. So if you mean "textbox" instead (because a label control can't be bound to a field of a table) then you can simply lock the textboxes itself to prevent them of being edited by the user. Go to the properties of the textboxes (you can click them together by holding down the shift key) and then select "Activated: No" and "Locked: Yes", that's all.

Cheers,

Christian

Comment: Yes, they are textboxes, but they act as field labels. So, the values that appear in the textboxes are the 'labels' for the checkboxes that they appear next to in the form. If the dropdown selector is changed, then the 'labels' change and the checkboxes then belong to a different category and have different meanings. I can't lock the textboxes, because this prevents the dropdown list from changing the values in the textboxes. I suppose I could password protect the textboxes, but not sure how to do this yet.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I didn't get an email notification. If you lock a control in a form there is no problem updating it programmatically. The lock only affects the user who cannot enter anything into the control, but VBA can change this without any problem.